# Switch vs map for command prompt loop

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that runs as a repeating command prompt. The user starts the program, then is prompted to enter commands until the command `exit` is entered. The way it works is that each command is represented by a class that inherits from a `CommandExecutor` interface I created, which has an `onCommand` method that is called when that particular command is entered.

Currently, I have a `HashMap<String, CommandExecutor>` in my main class that stores all of the commands and their corresponding executors. When the program is launched, each command is registered into the map like so:

```
Map<String, CommandExecutor> executors = new HashMap<String, CommandExecutor>();

executors.put("help", new HelpCommand());
executors.put("list", new ListCommand());
executors.put("update", new UpdateCommand());
executors.put("wizard", new Wizard());
executors.put("build", new BuildCommand());
executors.put("new", new NewCommand());
executors.put("select", new SelectCommand());
```

With this design, the program loop looks like this:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
boolean cont;

while(cont) {
    // Reads line, parses input:
    // String lastCommand for command
    // String[] parameters for parameters

    if(lastCommand.equals("exit") {
        cont = false;
    } else {
        if(!executors.containsKey(lastCommand))
            System.out.println("Unknown Command!");
        executors.get(lastCommand).onCommand(lastCommand, parameters);
    }
}
```

*Some code in the above snipets has been omitted for simplicity, as it is not relevant to this question.*

Is this the most efficient way to go about something like this, or would it be better to simply use a switch statement kind of like this:

```
CommandExecutor exec;

switch(lastInput) {
case "exit":
    cont = false;
    break;
case "help"
    exec = new HelpCommand();
    break;
case "list";
    exec = new ListCommand();
    break;
case "update";
    exec = new UpdateCommand();
    break;
// etc
default:
    System.out.println("Unknown Command!");
}

exec.onCommand(lastInput, parameters);
```

This isn't so much an issue of getting the program to work. Rather, it as a question of which design is going to be better in terms of efficiency and performance, as well as which one is simply going to yield better written code.

Comment: Readability is more important. The switch looks more readable to me. Opinion-based though. *shrug* Edit: Also given a sufficiently long list of commands, the switch becomes the less readable solution IMO.

Comment: Why not just use an Enum, and define the `onCommand` functionality as needed? Then do something like `Enum.valueOf(string)` to get the `Enum` value, and invoke `onCommand(params)`.

Comment: Just a thought, you could eliminate your if(command.equals("exit")) by implementing an exit command executor that calls System.exit()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original code is an application of the *Command* design pattern as described in the [GoF book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns). It uses polymorphism.

In contrast, according to Martin Fowler (in the first edition of "Refactoring"), a switch statement like this is a "bad smell in code":

> Most times you see a switch statement, you should consider polymorphism---Martin Fowler, Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code, 2000.

The last edition of the book retreats a bit from the hard line, but still includes it in the list, albeit with the qualifier "repeated":

> So we now focus on the repeated switch, where the same conditional switching logic (either in a switch/case statement or in a cascade of if/else statements) pops up in different places. The problem with such duplicate switches is that, whenever you add a clause, you have to find all the switches and update them. Against the dark forces of such repetition, polymorphism provides an elegant weapon for a more civilized codebase.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, there are two big factors to consider in this question. Readability and scalability.

#### Scalability

The switch statement requires that you have all your commands laid out at compile-time, and once that program starts running that switch isn't changing. Your usage of a Map is not limited by this. You can plug and play commands into that system at runtime. You could even make commands that spawn more commands. Besides, if you ever need to add a command you have to go right back to that switch statement and make a spot in the ever-growing list, which takes me to the next point.

#### Readability

When you have a couple commands its just as @arcadeblast77 said, the switch statement is more readable. If this is a homework assignment or a simple little project I would say a switch statement is fine. If you are planning something bigger however, I would suggest the Map structure. I shudder to think at what that switch statement would look like with 50+ commands loaded in.

That general structure also lends itself to the usage of [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). If you aren't already aware of it I would give it a look. It's some cool stuff that you might be interested in implementing.

Answer (score 0):

arcadeblast77 is right that the switch statement is more readable, but it's definitely less efficient. So it's a judgement call which you might choose to use.

But readability is easy to fix with a 1-line comment. This is how I would do that last bit of code:

```
else {
    // Commands are stored in a Map, so we can readily find them.
    if(!executors.containsKey(lastCommand)) {
        System.out.println("Unknown Command!");
        continue;
    }
    // Key exists, so it's safe to grab the object and run it.
    CommandExecutor exec = executors.get(lastCommand);
    exec.onCommand(lastCommand, parameters);
}
```

Breaking the one line into two is easier to read (in my opinion). The other way to do it might be like this:

```
    executors.get(lastCommand)
        .onCommand(lastCommand, parameters);
```

This is only clear if you use the "builder" model in your code, so people have grown accustomed to code that looks like this:

```
foo.setX(1)
   .setY(2)
   .setGleep("glop")
   ;
```

That is, if people are accustomed to run-on code where subsequent lines begin with a dot, so they know the previous line has a method call that returns an object you can continue to work on. Otherwise doing this in a very isolated fashion is going to confuse at least some programmers.

This answer is VERY subjective. Not everyone is going to agree with me.